# Cisco 1921 & Interfaces, and WAN IPs

Tags: cisco, router, wide-area-network, interface

Would it be possible to have more than 1 WAN IP on a single interface on a Cisco 1921 router? (This is an actual argument going on with another engineer haha).

From my understanding, you would need to introduce additional modules or WICs to have more WAN IPs on the Cisco 1921 (assuming the two Gigabit Ethernet interfaces built into it are used up).

Comment: Do you plan to have the public IPs NAT back to the same subnet or do each IP route to different subnets?

Comment: What about VLAN? You can create 4096 subinterfaces on one physical interface.

Answer (score 0):

An IP address is an IP address. There really isn't any distinction between what is a WAN address vs. a LAN address.

Cisco routers allow you to use secondary IPv4 addresses on interfaces. You could also certainly have both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on an interface, and IPv6 specifically allows, even requires, multiple addresses on an interface.

Also, depending on how you count an interface, you can have multiple subinterfaces, each with a different IP addresses, for each physical interface. When using frame relay, you could assign different addresses to different DLCIs on the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes. You don't need the extra WIC, unless you're specifically using multiple physical links.  If you're using 1 physical link, you can use multiple public IPs one interface.

However, without knowing how your public IPs translate to your internal networking, giving you explicit instructions is difficult.

You can do this using a NAT overload on the WAN interface and using route-maps and ACLs to determine what traffic goes where for a single subnet.  For example, this is a basic entry for my WAN interface, where `a.b.c.d` is a public IP from my available pool, and `255.255.255.240` is the associated subnet mask. I also use an ACL here to determine what traffic I let in:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
  ip address a.b.c.d 255.255.255.240
  ip access-group ACLINCOMING in
```

This is where I define my ACL for incoming traffic, where `a.b.c.d`, `a.b.c.x`, `a.b.c.y`, `a.b.c.z` are different public IPs in my available pool:

```
ip access-list extended ACLINCOMING
   permit tcp any host a.b.c.d eq 22
   permit tcp any host a.b.c.d eq telnet
   permit tcp any host a.b.c.x eq 443
   permit tcp any host a.b.c.x eq www
   permit udp any host a.b.c.y isakmp
   permit udp any host a.b.c.y eq non500-isakmp
   permit tcp any host a.b.c.z eq ftp-data
   permit tcp any host a.b.c.z eq ftp
```

This is the base NAT config for host to public IP definition, where `a.b.c.x`, `a.b.c.y`, `a.b.c.z` are different public IPs in my available pool

```
ip nat inside source list ACLNATOVERLOAD interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
ip nat inside source static 10.10.10.100 a.b.c.x route-map RMAPSTATICNAT
ip nat inside source static 10.10.10.101 a.b.c.y route-map RMAPSTATICNAT
ip nat inside source static 10.10.10.102 a.b.c.z route-map RMAPSTATICNAT
```

This extended ACL prevents anything from accessing the specific hosts, `10.10.10.100`, `10.10.10.101` and `10.10.10.102`, unless it is defined in the ACLINCOMING ACL

```
ip access-list extended ACLNATOVERLOAD
  deny   ip host 10.10.10.100 any
  deny   ip host 10.10.10.101 any
  deny   ip host 10.10.10.102 any
  permit ip 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

This route-map lets takes care of the translations

```
route-map RMAPSTATICNAT permit 10
  match ip address ACLSTATICNAT
```

This lets those hosts route traffic using the route-map above

```
ip access-list extended ACLSTATICNAT
  permit ip host 10.10.10.100 any
  permit ip host 10.10.10.101 any
  permit ip host 10.10.10.102 any
```

Other people may have a better way, but this is what I basically have set up.